# Using replacement to construct the $\omega^{th}$ powerset of a set

Tags: set-theory

As I understand it, the axiom of replacement in $ZFC$ says that

> **Replacement**. For any binary predicate $\phi(\cdot,\cdot)$ and any set $x$ such that for all members $x'\in x$ there exists some (unique in some formalisms, not necessarily in others) set $y$ such that $\phi(x',y)=\top$, there exists a set $z$ whose members are precisely the sets $y$ such that there exists some $x'\in x$ with $\phi(x',y)=\top$.

With powersets taken as an axiom, to construct $\mathcal{P}^\omega(x)$ for a set $x$ can we consider the binary predicate $$\phi(\cdot,\cdot)\equiv\mathcal{P}^\cdot(x)=\cdot$$ and observe that for $\omega$ we have that for all $n<\omega$ we tautologically have $\phi(n,\mathcal{P}^n(x))$, allowing us to form the set $z$ consisting of all finite powersets of $x$, so $$z=\{\mathcal{P}^n(x):n<\omega\}?$$ Is there a less tautological binary predicate to consider for this construction, if this one does work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\phi$ you've written isn't actually a formula in the language of set theory (even if we grant "$\mathcal{P}$" as an abbreviation); this is, I think, what creates its "tautologous" feel.

Instead, we need to work with **sequences** directly. Use the following formula (taking $\mathcal{P}$ as an abbreviation for simplicity):

> $\delta(a,b;x)\equiv$ "$a$ is an ordinal, $b$ is a sequence of length $a+1$, $b(0)=x$, and for all $i\le a$ we have $b(i+1)=\mathcal{P}(b(i))$."

Applying Replacement to $\delta$ with "source-of-$a$s set" $\omega$ we form the set $$\{\langle x\rangle, \langle x,\mathcal{P}(x)\rangle, \langle x,\mathcal{P}(x),\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(x))\rangle,...\}$$ and from there we can get the desired $\mathcal{P}^\omega(x)$ via union/separation shenanigans as usual. Note that this is exactly the same trick we use for forming recursive definitions in arithmetic!

*Exercise: how do we tweak $\delta$ to let us make sense of $\mathcal{P}^\alpha(x)$ for any set $x$ and ordinal $\alpha$?*

Comment: Thank you as always Noah!

Comment: @AlecRhea Glad to help!

Comment: 2 questions: should the inequality in the highlighted part read ‘…for all $i<a+1$…’ instead of $i<x$? and is it bad form to guess at exercises on MSE (are they intended for future readers) or is the OP meant to answer them? Or is there no custom and I’m just overthinking it? (so 3 questions technically I suppose)

Comment: I believe I understand the exercise, but I’m confused about the highlighted part — how does $i\leq x$ make sense if $x$ is just a set and not an ordinal, a-priori? ($x$ was just a set in my question, and I don’t see you specify that it’s an ordinal anywhere). Out of curiosity, is the $\phi$ I wrote a formula in the language of second/third order set theory?

Comment: @AlecRhea Sorry, that $x$ should be $a$ - fixed! (And the issue with your formula isn't the order of the logic used, it's that it uses the notation "$\mathcal{P}^-(-)$" which isn't primitive.)