# Cumulative hierarchy construction in ZFC, category of sets in ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

This is probably a dumb question, but

> How is the proof that all sets lie inside the cumulative hierarchy carried out in $ZFC$?

In particular, I'd like to understand it in ZFC and not GBC/MK or any other system allowing reference to proper classes. The text I use for a reference is Donald Monk's [Introduction to Set Theory](http://euclid.colorado.edu/%7Emonkd/monk11.pdf) (where the system used is MK) -- he constructs the rank function $\rho$ on the universe (p.112) by recursion as $$\rho(x)=\min\{\alpha:\forall y\in x(\rho(y)<\alpha)\}$$ then proceeds to show that rank interacts with powersets etc. in the expected way, defining ${\bf M}_\alpha$ to mean the $\alpha^{th}$ stage of the cumulative hierarchy (all sets of rank less than $\alpha$), showing that $\mathcal{P}({\bf M}_\alpha)={\bf M}_{\alpha+1}$, that ${\bf M}_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}M_\beta$ for limit $\alpha$, and finally that $V=\bigcup_{\alpha\in O_n}{\bf M}_\alpha$.

This is all done in MK, so statements like '$V=\bigcup_{\alpha\in O_n}{\bf M}_\alpha$' have a well defined meaning, but if we drop down to $ZFC$ this statement isn't well defined since the left and right hand sides aren't sets.

> Is there a standard reference for this construction carried out in $ZFC$, or could someone give a quick sketch of how to view the cumulative hierarchy from within $ZFC$ and how to state the fact that all sets appear inside it?

I could see a 'Scott's trick' statement like $\forall x\exists\alpha(x\in{\bf M}_\alpha)$ standing in for $V=\bigcup_{\alpha\in O_n}{\bf M}_\alpha$; is this the standard approach?

On a related note, what is the standard definition of the category of sets in $ZFC$? As far as I'm aware we at least need to be able to define the 'collection of objects' for a category, wether we want to use the one hom-set definition or the many hom-set definition; how is the category of sets usually defined within ZFC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking this. The $\mathsf{MK}$ approach you describe does not use $\mathsf{MK}$, or indeed classes at all, in any essential way. To $\mathsf{ZFC}$ify it, we just replace the **specific** classes used with their defining formulas. For example, we can whip up a formula $\rho(x,y)$ which intuitively says "$y$ is an ordinal and $x$ has rank $\le y$." The theorem you're asking about just says "$\forall x\exists y(\rho(x,y))$," and there are no subtleties in porting over the proof: basically, using the term "non-cumulative" to refer to a putative counterexample, we show that every non-cumulative set must have a non-cumulative element and then apply regularity *(after constructing the transitive closure and applying separation, if you want to avoid using choice)*.

Or, as in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471393/), we can use *sequences* to prove a sharper result. First, we prove that for every ordinal $\alpha$ there is exactly one sequence $s_\alpha$ of length $\alpha$ such that $s_\alpha(0)=\emptyset$, $s_\alpha(\beta+1)=\mathcal{P}(s_\alpha(\beta))$ for $\beta+1<\alpha$, and $s_\alpha(\lambda)=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda}s_\alpha(\beta)$ for $\lambda<\alpha$ a limit. This $s_\alpha$ is just $\langle V_\beta\rangle_{\beta<\alpha}$. We can then prove that every set is an element of $s_{\alpha+1}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$, using exactly the same outline above. *(And actually this isn't really any different from the previous paragraph, since sequences are already used in this exact way in the construction of $\rho$.)*

None of this in any way goes outside $\mathsf{ZFC}$, or even $\mathsf{ZF}$. Replacement is necessary, however; for example, it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZC}$ (= $\mathsf{ZFC}$ minus replacement) that $V_\omega$ doesn't exist, so a fortiori only finite sets are contained in the cumulative hierarchy.

---

As to the category of sets, just use the formula $x=x$. In $\mathsf{ZFC}$, **all things are sets**, so the object-class is just the universe itself.

Comment: Thank you for this; the issue is that I’m secretly not working in ZFC, I’m working in a [theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.03169) where the primitives are already classes and I would like to carry out cumulative hierarchies ‘on top’ of universes and make reference to ‘the category of all classes’ and things like this (because I hate myself, apparently). I would like to avoid iterating the ‘set->class primitive change’ trick if possible, so I was hoping to use the treatment of proper classes in ZFC as a ‘muse’ for how to treat ‘really proper classes’ in this theory.

Comment: (the linked version there doesn’t have replacement for classes added yet, but I’ve added it in my personal notes that I’ll upload at some point)

Comment: If we work in second order ZFC, is the universe of sets a legitimate second order object of discourse?

Comment: @AlecRhea I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you're trying to do then. I'd recommend (precisely formuating and) asking the question you actually care about.

Comment: Fair enough, apologies for muddying the waters.